# Find the surface of a triangle between two slopes and x axis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Find the surface of the triangle between this two slopes and x axis.

$$f(x)=x+1$$
$$g(x)=(3-2\sqrt{2})x$$
So : $\text{k}_1= \arctan(1)=45$° and

$\text{k}_2=\arctan(3-2\sqrt{2})=?$
It's very hard to get this angle without a calculator, which I must not use.

Then I tried:
$$\tan(\psi)=|\frac{\text{k}_1-\text{k}_2}{1+\text{k}_2\text{k}_1}| $$
I got: $\psi=45$°
So the angles are: $\alpha=45$°,  $\psi=45$°,  $\beta=90$°

But how to get surface of the triangle only from these data?

EDIT: Also the $\arctan(3-2\sqrt2)$ is not 90 degrees. This frustrates me? What should I do? Actually mathematica says it is:$\,9,736$°

Comment: What do you need the angles for? Isn't the base of the triangle equal to $1$ and the height of the triangle equal to the absolute value of the $y$-coordinate of the point of intersection of the two lines?

Comment: @trancelocation How do you know that the base equals 1

Comment: One line intersects the $x$-axis at $-1$. The other line goes through the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersect when $$x+1=(3-2\sqrt2)x \implies x=-\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)}{2} $$ and $$y=x+1=\frac{1-\sqrt 2}{2}$$ The other vertices of the triangle are the $ x$-intercepts of the lines, namely $(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. So the area is simply

$$\frac 12\left|\begin{matrix} -\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)}{2} &\frac{1-\sqrt 2}{2} & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right| $$

Comment: Can you explain how does the discriminant work to calculate surface? I know the basics of discriminant, but not how to calculate the surface.

Comment: The discriminant can be thought of as a cross product, which describes how area is scaled in the typical case. For example, $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = ||a|| \, ||b||\sin{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle in between the vectors. This should look familiar because it is twice the area of a triangle. This answer is just a method of finding the area of a triangle using only the coordinates of the vertices, which can be thought of as vectors.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x+1$ intersects the $x$-axis at $(-1,0)$ and $g(x)=(3-2\sqrt{2})x$ intersects the x-axis at $(0,0)$. Finally $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersect at $(\frac{1}{2-2\sqrt{2}},\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{2-2\sqrt{2}})$. So what are the base and height of the triangle?.